# JSON Decode playlist Items of Youtube videos

Tags: json, jsondecoder

```
$sermonurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=PLPdCOInvZ99qcDOJnaWmHJIs-ACbRseJY&key=XXXXXXXAPIKEYXXXXXXXXXXX";
$sermoncontents = file_get_contents($sermonurl);
$videocontent = json_decode($sermoncontents);
$videotitle = $videocontent->items[0]->snippet->title;
$videothumbnail = $videocontent->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->maxres->url;

return  $videothumbnail;
```

This has been working suddenly stopped... Not sure what happened.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Show please console.log($sermoncontents). So I can see which json have you got)

Comment: It's just blank.. If I do var_dump(json_decode(sermoncontents)) I get NULL. It stopped suddenly.. Thanks aidonline01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with your key, I checked with mine, and it's working fine. Please run this code with your key, and check console for details

```js
let YourKey = '';

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=PLPdCOInvZ99qcDOJnaWmHJIs-ACbRseJY&key=' + YourKey,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error.responseText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Daily Limit Exceeded. - Oops.. Not sure how this happened

Comment: If my answer helped you, choose it please as correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you should not use "let YourKey = '';" (es6). Because it will not work in IE.

-> var YourKey = '';